# Python - can't make number in variable higher

Tags: python, variables, pong

I'm programming game pong in python and I wan't the ball to be faster everytime it bounces of a bat. So I tried to add

```
global SPEED
SPEED + 25
```

into a function higher_speed which will trigger everytime when the ball bounces of the bat.
short version of game code here:

```
...

BALL_SIZE = 20
BAT_WIDTH = 10
BAT_HEIGHT = 100
SPEED = 250  # (in pixels per second)
BAT_SPEED = SPEED * 1.5  # (in pixels per second)

...

def higher_speed(SPEED, x):
    x = 25
    global SPEED
    SPEED + x
    return SPEED

    # bounce left
    if ball_position[0] < BAT_WIDTH + BALL_SIZE / 2:
        if bat_min < bat_position[0] < bat_max:
            # bat bounces ball
            BALL_SPEED[0] = abs(BALL_SPEED[0])
            global SPEED
            higher_speed()
        else:
            # bat hadn't bounced the ball, player loses
            score[1] += 1
            reset()

    # bounce right
    if ball_position[0] > WIDTH7777 - (BAT_WIDTH + BALL_SIZE / 2):
        if bat_min < bat_position[1] < bat_max:
            BALL_SPEED[0] = -abs(BALL_SPEED[0])
            higher_speed()
        else:
            score[0] += 1
            reset()

...
```

*Please help. I appreciate your time :).*

Comment: You probably mean `SPEED += x` instead of `SPEED + x` - this does not do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things here:

First of all, the value is not being changed because it is not assigned in the first place, your function should look like this:

```
def higher_speed(SPEED, x):
    x=25
    global SPEED
    SPEED += x
```

Second, if you're overwriting `x` at the beginning of the function and using `SPEED` as global, why pass it?:

```
def higher_speed():
    global SPEED
    SPEED += 25
```

Third, according to Python's [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants) standards, capitalized words are only for constants, it would be a good use to the speed increase, so it should look like this:

```
SPEED_INCREASE = 25

def higher_speed():
    global speed
    speed += SPEED_INCREASE
```

And last, in general is a bad idea using global variables you can check [this article](https://algorithmsandme.com/five-reasons-why-not-to-use-global-variables/) or google it, so try to avoid it, then it should look like this:

```
def higher_speed(speed):
    return speed+SPEED_INCREASE

speed = higher_speed(speed)
```

or you could set this inline:

```
speed += SPEED_INCREASE
```

I hope it helped!